# categories for protocols and warnings "class does not implement protocol"

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-category

Well, I have these two protocols:

```
@protocol ivAuthorizationProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)loginReply:(ivSession*)session;
@end
@protocol ivServerListsProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)serverListLoaded:(NSArray*)serverList;
@end
```

and have class

```
@interface ivClientAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
...
@end
@implementation
...
-(void)authorizeWithLogin:(NSString*)login andPassword:(NSString*)password
{
    self.login = login;
    self.password = password;
    // !!! delegate in the next call should conform to ivAuthorizationProtocol, 
    // so i get warning "class does not implement protocol ivAuthoriaztionProtocol" here
    [_apiWrapper authorizeWith:login andPassword:password forDelegate:self]; 
}
...
@end
```

I want to put the implementation of the protocol's methods in separate files (categories) so not to mess up the main implementation file. For example, the header of the category for implementation of ivAuthorizationProtocol looks like this:

```
#import "ivClientAppDelegate.h"

@interface ivClientAppDelegate (ivAuthorizationResponder) <ivAuthorizationProtocol>
-(void)loginReply:(ivSession*)session;
@end
```

So, the question is - how can I get rid of the warning I get in the main implementation file? How can I tell the compiler that methods conforming to the protocol are located in categories?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you import the header files of the categories?

Comment: yes, i've imported them. but if i import ivAuthorizationProtocol in main implementation i will get warning about not implementing ivAuthorizationProtocol methods, what is also not nice =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a cast to silence the warning:

```
[_apiWrapper
    authorizeWith:login
    andPassword:password
    forDelegate:(id<ivAuthorizationProtocol>)self
];
```

Other than that, you can't do what you want without getting different warnings (unimplemented methods). Normally you would specify the protocol in the interface:

```
@interface ivClientAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,ivAuthorizationProtocol
```

But then you would need to implement the methods in you main `@implementation` block.

Please note that by convention class and protocol names should start with an uppercase character.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you consider doing it like this:

```
         @interface ivClientAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, ivAuthorizationProtocol >
```

Comment: so i will have to implement protocol methods in main implementation file, cause compiler will generate the same warning "class does not implement protocol ivAuthoriaztionProtocol". but i want protocol methods implementation in category file. and no warnings=)

Answer (score 0):

Declaring protocol method as optional will fix the issue.